# displaying special characters in hyperlink text

Tags: java, html, jsp, hyperlink, anchor

I have used HTML in my Java class and in one case I have used `<a href="...">username</a>`. Username is a variable that gets values dynamically. In one case its value is 'rg@bg' but here instead of the name I'm getting the URL to which it is directed in my jsp. How do I ensure that the value of username comes on the display page as it is. 
I have tried "@"+username. Didn't work

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify what the variable is suppose to contain, what the expected output is, what the actual output is, and how the line looks like that does the printing.

Comment: the variable contains usernames. example-'xyz','tim','ab@db' expected output whn input is ab@db is a hyperlink with text ab@db and actual output is the url mentioned in the href

Comment: you forgot how the line looks like that does the printing.

Comment: You must be leaving something out. @ isn't a special character neither in HTML nor in Java strings.

Comment: html.append("\"style=\"text-align:left;\"  colspan=\"2\"  style=\"background:#ffffff;;border-right:1px solid #ffffff\">") ;
                html.append("<a href=\"" + "xyz.do?"+"\">");
                 html.append(username+"</a></th>");


this works fine for all other names. and also the value is 'ab@db' whn i take d mouse over it. only the diplay is of thr url that it is directed to. 

this is part of d tag definition.the line tht does the printing just calls the tag.

Comment: Sorry, but the way how you abuse English and the lack of demonstrable amount of effort does really not encourage me to answer this question. Read [this link](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have greasemonkey installed which automatically converts email patterns into links?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but here is a guess.

I suspect you do the actual print wrong. If the variable is called `username` and "username" is printed instead of the content of `username` it seems you need to do something like

```
print("<a href=\"...\">" + username + "</a>");
```

instead of

```
print("<a href=\"...\">username</a>");
```

In jsp you could also simply write

```
<a href="..."><%= username %></a>
```

---

If the problem concerns treatment of html-entities you may find the following interesting:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0306.html

Comment: no i am not getting it as username. i m getting d url it has to be directed to. it works fine for all other names